# Determining which trigger in TeamCity started my build

Tags: triggers, teamcity

My build configuration has 2 triggers;

- Finish Build Trigger - Waits for a successfull build of another
  project
- VCS Trigger - Checks if certain files have been    changed/updated

I'm not entirely sure I have my VCS Trigger setup correctly but I can't seem to find out which trigger is starting the build to confirm my suspicions, is there a feature for this?

Answer (score 4):

On the build overview page (), there is a section called `Triggered by` (it is on the right-hand side, under the `Agent` section), where you can see if it was Git, or schedule trigger, or snapshot dependency, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Under your projects configuration, look at Build Chains. This should help give some clarity.

[image]

Comment: Had a quick read of the docs, it seems I need to have a Snapshot Dependancy to see this menu item?! https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Chain